# vectorize a function for numpy, that correlates each element of one vector with each element of another

Tags: python, numpy, vector

I have a function that takes two elements of two vector and calculates a scalar value. How can I vectorize this function using the numpy tools, so that I can write

```
A = my_func(vec_a, vec_b)
```

where `A` is then a matrix of dimension `len(vec_a) x len(vec_b)`. How can I do that? Or must I iterate in the `my_func` expilicitely?
As a bonus: The matrix will be very sparse, i.e., many of the calculated values in `my_func` are zero. Is it possible to include this sparsity in the implementation?

---

As requested, an example:

Suppose I have two vectors `a` and `b`:

```
a = numpy.array([...]) # length n
b = numpy.array([...]) # length m
```

Now, I want to call `my_func(a,b)` and have it return a sparse matrix, whose dense representation would be

```
A = [
        [my_func(a[0], b[0]), my_func(a[0], b[1]), ..., my_func(a[0], b[n])],
        [my_func(a[1], b[0]), my_func(a[1], b[1]), ..., my_func(a[1], b[n])],
        ...
        [my_func(a[m], b[0]), my_func(a[m], b[1]), ..., my_func(a[m], b[n])]
]
```

A lot of the entries would, of course, be zero.

---

As requested, the `my_func` function.

```
# note, that each element of the above vectors is a 
# list itself, with 4 elements. 
def my_func(a, b):
    distance = sp.sqrt(sp.sum((a[1:] - b[1:])**2))
    rate = sp.exp(-2*distance/loclength)

    if a[0] < b[0]:
        rate *= sp.exp((a[0] - b[0])/kT)

    return rate if rate > cutoff else 0
```

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: To vectorize the function, we need to know the implementation of my_func.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using broadcasting appropriately:

```
def my_func_vec(a, b):
    a = np.array(a, copy=False, ndmin=2)
    b = np.array(b, copy=False, ndmin=2)
    a = a[..., np.newaxis, :]
    b = b[..., np.newaxis, :, :]
    distance = np.sqrt(np.sum((a[..., 1:] - b[..., 1:])**2, axis=-1))
    rate = np.exp(-2*distance / loclength)
    mask = a[..., 0] < b[..., 0]
    rate[mask] *= np.exp((a[..., 0] - b[..., 0])[mask] / kT)
    mask = rate <= cutoff
    rate[mask] = 0
    return rate
```

To test it set some dummy values:

```
loclength = 1
kT = 1
cutoff = 0.25
a = np.random.rand(3, 5)
b = np.random.rand(4, 5)
```

And now:

```
>>> my_func_vec(a, b)
array([[ 0.34220076,  0.        ,  0.25392478,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.25953994,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Instead of:

```
>>> out = np.empty((3, 4))
>>> for r, j in enumerate(a):
...     for c, k in enumerate(b):
...         out[r, c] = my_func(j, k)
... 
>>> out
array([[ 0.34220076,  0.        ,  0.25392478,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.25953994,  0.        ,  0.        ]])
```

Comment: Hi Jaime, thank you for the suggestion. It will take some time to digest the numpy magic, though. :)